# how to make a custom audioplayer play songs hosted online

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html5-audio

I want to use a custom audio player to play sound tracks hosted online.

For example I want to be able to feed the audio player a link like
example.com/path/to/track.mp3
and it should parse it and play it. I can play sound tracks hosted locally

Here is the code where I have the problem. I have an audio object that points to a local folder where the sound tracks are. I am not sure how to deal with this when it is not hosted locally.

When I replace the path with the URL the audio player just freezes.

```js
$(function () {
    var count = 0;
    var audio;

    //Hide Pause
    $('#pause').hide();

    initAudio($('#playlist li:first-child'));

    function initAudio(element) {
        var song = element.attr('song');
        var cover = element.attr('cover');
        var artist = element.attr('artist');
        var title = element.text();
        var temp = parseFloat($('#volume-slider').val() / 100);

        //Create audio object
        audio = new Audio('../media/books/' + song);

        audio.volume = temp;

        audio.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function () {
            minutes = parseInt(audio.duration / 60);
            seconds = parseInt(audio.duration % 60);

            if (seconds < 10) {
                seconds = '0' + seconds;
            };
            if (minutes < 10) {
                minutes = '0' + minutes;
            };
        
            $('#duration').html(minutes + ':' + seconds);
        });

        $("#auto-play").click(function () {
            if (count === 1) {
                $("#auto-play").css("background-color", "black");
                count = 0;
            } else {
                $("#auto-play").css("background-color", "rgb(0,0,255)");
                count = 1;
            }
        });

        audio.addEventListener('ended', function () {
            if (count > 0) {
                var next = $('#playlist li.active').next();
                if (next.length == 0) {
                    next = $('#playlist li:first-child');
                }
                initAudio($(next));
                audio.play();
                showCurrentTime();
            }
        });

        //Inserts track info
        $('.artist').text(artist);
        $('.title').text(title);
        $('#duration').text();
        //Insert song cover. NOTE: the path below is relative to the 
        //html "img.cover" element not this js file.
        $('img.cover').attr('src', '../media/books/covers/' + cover);
        $('#playlist li').removeClass('active');
        element.addClass('active');
    };
});
```

Comment: Do you get some errors in the console? Maybe something like CORS.

Comment: Hi brandit yes i do it say access to xmlhttprequest at (the link) from origin null is blocked by CORS policy. i have little experince in networking and not sure why this is the case. Is there a way to implement this in a simpler manner? Thanks

Comment: My goal is to scan and list all soundtracks in a given link. Then create a playlist and be able to play them.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid CORS errors with something [like this](https://dev.to/andypotts/avoiding-cors-errors-on-localhost-in-2020-4mfn).
For your local development it would be easy.
If you would like to go in production, it would be bit harder. The Server with the soundtracks has to accept your App.

Comment: Thank you again i will look into the link now. The server belong to archive.org and they do have an api if thats what you mean